# Android FDE security leaks | how it effect apps

Tags: android

Recently I went through a blog which states about android full disk encryption security issue.. Can someone please tell how it effect the application

http://indianexpress.com/article/technology/tech-news-technology/android-full-disk-encryption-fde-flaw-could-affect-millions-of-phones-report-2893129/

Answer (score 0):

It does not affect apps, insofar as apps work with and without full-disk encryption. In fact, the vast majority of apps do not know whether they are running on an encrypted device or not.

It affects *users* of apps, who may think that their full-disk-encrypted data is more secure than it really is. It may cause developers of apps to elect to offer in-app encryption (e.g., SQLCipher for Android).

Comment: Am using account authenticator for keeping the Oauth token and sandbox for db ... is it create issue ??

Comment: @Bytecode: Not really. It means that if the user is kidnapped by criminals, or is arrested by police, that those groups might be able to get at the OAuth token. In those cases, the user has far bigger problems.